# Popcorn and 18.04.1

Tags: software-uninstall

I have a double question after failing to properly install Popcorn time because I could not extract to /opt as per information I gathered but somehow managed to copy the app in the folder but it does not execute

I would now like to reinstall it or else remove it.

Questions are:
1. How to re-install popcorn properly 
2. Else how to remove the sub-folder and/or application. 
None of the tips/answers I could read worked for any of the 2 especially that gksudo is removed.

Note: Download source is https://popcorntime.sh/ and Ubuntu version is 18.04.1 64 bit

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with removing a partially installed program. Uninstalling via the terminal did not work at all, as when entering `dpkg --list` , the package still "existed" in this list, although its files were removed.

Because I'm fairly new to linux, I used the Synaptic Package Manager. This made the process a lot easier for me, as it displays a GUI.

First, installing the package manager.

```bsh
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

You will need admin privileges to open this

```bsh
sudo synaptic
```

Finally, select *Search* and enter the package/application name. Right-click it and select *Mark for Complete Removal*. After this select *Apply* then confirm, and you're done.

Comment: Popcorn Time was not installed by apt.

Comment: did you use a _.deb_ file?

Comment: Popcorn Time was not installed by a .deb file.

Comment: @karel
I'm sorry that I could not help :( . It seems that the download link is a _tar.xz_ file.

I have searched around and found that to uninstall the application, enter this from the folder's directory into the terminal - as root...
```
    make clean;
    make uninstall;
```
If that fails an app called _checkinstall_ may help form a package that can then be uninstalled.
[https://asic-linux.com.mx/~izto/checkinstall/index.php]

I found this on :
[https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/showthread.php?threadid=358787]

Edit: Forgive my formatting, this is new to me :P